# How to create a dictionary from a file in python

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I have a file like this :

```
group #1
a b c d
e f g h

group #2
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

How can I make this into a dictionary like this:

```
{'group #1' : [[a, b, c, d], [e, f, g, h]], 
 'group #2' :[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]}
```

Comment: And what did you try so far? What didn't work, what did, what are you struggling with right now?

Answer (score 3):

```
file = open("file","r")                       # Open file for reading 
dic = {}                                      # Create empty dic

for line in file:                             # Loop over all lines in the file
        if line.strip() == '':                # If the line is blank
            continue                          # Skip the blank line
        elif line.startswith("group"):        # Else if line starts with group
            key = line.strip()                # Strip whitespace and save key
            dic[key] = []                     # Initialize empty list
        else:
            dic[key].append(line.split())     # Not key so append values

print dic
```

Output:

```
{'group #2': [['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['5', '6', '7', '8']], 
 'group #1': [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']]}
```

Comment: You probably want `line.split()` in `dic[key].append(..)` to match what OP wants.

Comment: NP.  I like the all the comments! :-)

Comment: the checking of blank lines is redundant here.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid it's not, you would end up with an extra empty list for each blank line.

Comment: @sudo_O see mgilson's answer for what I mean.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid mgilson code also acconts for blank lines `elif line.strip()` it's not redundant it's required.

Comment: Agreed, however the way you have written it is not the generally accepted pattern in Python, it works, but its better written as `if not line.strip():`

Comment: Wasn't going for most `pythonic` code, was going conceptually easy python code for a noob to understand, but I take your point.

Comment: `line.strip().split()` is redundant though :).  It's exactly the same as `line.split()`.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the file until you find a "group" tag.  Add a new list to your dictionary with that tag.  Then append lines to that tag until you hit another "group" tag.

*untested*

```
d = {}
for line in fileobject:
    if line.startswith('group'):
        current = d[line.strip()] = []
    elif line.strip() and d:
        current.append(line.split())
```